# Removing several anchor points in a path quickly -using a box for example- (Illustrator CC)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, anchor-point

If I have an anchor points path of a deformed box, and I want to remove all the points except the base (the bottom line), is it possible to remove them quickly? maybe using a box selection, is it possible the box selection causes the path to move

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the lasso tool (shortcut Q) you can quickly select the anchor points you want to delete, when selected you can press the delete key to delete the anchors.

Comment: Its deleting the path lines too. Is there a way to delete only anchor points of a selected area?